# How to Strip Slashes and the Numeric Content Between Them in a String

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip

Consider the following string:

```
/0123456789/abcdefg
```

I need to remove all the numbers between the two slashes as well as remove the slashes, too. I know about `preg_replace`, but have never worked with this function (am new to PHP). How would I make a correct regex for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want like this:-https://eval.in/857561 . Also some question like- digits can come in middle and last also? Or your each string will be exactly in this format `/number/string-without-any-number`?

Comment: string will always like this: /0123456789/sometext, i need just strip all numbers between slashes, and strip slashes too, for clearly echo of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way without `preg_replace()`:-

```
<?php

$url = "/0123456789/abcdefg";
echo $words = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

https://3v4l.org/IbG7E

Note:- [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) gets the position of the last occurrence of the slash; [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) returns everything after that position.

[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) function started counting the position of the given character from 0 that's why +1 is added to get the actual position from where the sub-string can be taken out

Answer (score 1):

The OP's question concerns a *regular expression* (regex) for use with **preg_replace()** to solve the matter.  Here's how:

```
<?php

$url = "/0123456789/abcdefg";

$regex= "~/\d+/~";

$replace = "";

echo preg_replace( $regex, $replace,$url );
```

See [live code.](https://3v4l.org/GUtm4)

Note that the regex consists of a forward slash, followed by one or more digits followed by another forward slash. The delimiters themselves use the character "~".  If instead they consisted of slashes, then and only then would one need to escape the forward slashes.

Incidentally, you could also achieve the desired output using preg_split(), as follows:

```
<?php

$url = "/0123456789/abcdefg";
list(,, $strData) = preg_split("~/~",$url );
echo $strData;
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/WtNls#output)

In this solution, the url string is split on the existence of a forward slash into a list that ignores the extraneous data while capturing the alphabetical string.

A better solution entails using explode() so that a string may contain less, more or the same number of forward slashes. Given a string terminated with alphabetical characters, one may code as follows:

```
   <?php

    $url = "/0123456789/abcdefg";
    $arrData = explode("/", $url );
    $dex = count($arrData) - 1;
    echo $arrData[ $dex ];
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/FpM9P)